# CodeBuild failed for cross-account CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to follow this guide to setup a cross accounts pipeline: https://taimos.de/blog/create-a-cicd-pipeline-for-your-cdk-app

I have Alpha account `111111` which will hold the pipeline, that is going to deploy to Alpha account `111111` and Prod account `222222`. I did the bootstrap below to establish a trust relationship to the CI/CD account to allow cross-account deployments.

```
cdk bootstrap --profile=eCommerceService-Prod --bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess' --trust 111111 --trust-for-lookup 111111  aws://222222/us-east-1
```

The pipeline is setup correctly, however, the ColdBuild failed:

[image]

> User: arn:aws:sts::111111:assumed-role/eCommerceDatabaseCdk-Pipe-PipelineBuildSynthCdkBui-JE7GJT5LX3SC/AWSCodeBuild-32197845-1f33-44c4-a9ff-d33aae93448e is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::222222:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-222222-us-east-1 . Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.

I checked that `arn:aws:iam::222222:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-222222-us-east-1`  exists in prod account. So it seems to me that there is a missing permission in the codebuild step. However, I did not find anything particular for CodeBuild step in this blog: https://taimos.de/blog/create-a-cicd-pipeline-for-your-cdk-app.

The permissions for role `arn:aws:iam::222222:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-222222-us-east-1`  mentioned in the error message is here:

[image]

It's trust entities is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

## Code

Pipeline config:

```js
export const pipelineStageInfoList: PipelineStageInfo[] = [
    {
        stageName: "ALPHA",
        awsAccount: "111111",
        awsRegion: "us-east-1"
    },
    {
        stageName: "PROD",
        awsAccount: "222222",
        awsRegion: "us-east-1"
    }
]
```

Pipeline stack:

```js
export class PipelineStack extends Cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Cdk.App, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Initialize the pipeline
    const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, "Pipeline", {
      pipelineName: "eCommerceDatabasePipeline",

      // Create KMS keys for the artifact buckets, 
      // allowing cross-account deployments
      crossAccountKeys: true,

      // allow the pipeline to reconfigure itself when assets or stages 
      // are being added to it
      selfMutation: true,

      // synth is expected to produce the CDK Cloud Assembly as its output
      synth: new pipelines.ShellStep("Synth", {
        input: pipelines.CodePipelineSource.gitHub(
          "pandanyc/eCommerceDatabaseCdk",
          "main",
          {
            authentication: Cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager('github-token')
          }
        ),
        // Install dependencies, build and run cdk synth
        commands: [
          'npm ci',
          'npm run build',
          'npx cdk synth'
        ],
      }),
    });

    // Add stages to this pipeline.
    pipelineStageInfoList.forEach((pipelineStage: PipelineStageInfo) => {
      pipeline.addStage(
        new ApplicationStage(this, pipelineStage.stageName, {
          stageName: pipelineStage.stageName,
          pipelineName: props.pipelineName,
          env: {
            account: pipelineStage.awsAccount,
            region: pipelineStage.awsRegion,
          },
        })
      );

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the permissions of the role in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform lookups in the pipeline itself, your synth step has to have the explicit permission to assume the lookup role. You would add it like this:

```typescript
synth: new pipelines.CodeBuildStep("Synth", {
    input: pipelines.CodePipelineSource.gitHub(
      "pandanyc/eCommerceDatabaseCdk",
      "main",
      {
        authentication: Cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager('github-token')
      }
    ),
    // Install dependencies, build and run cdk synth
    commands: [
      'npm ci',
      'npm run build',
      'npx cdk synth'
    ],
    rolePolicyStatements: [ iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
        resources: ['*'],
        conditions: { StringEquals: { 'iam:ResourceTag/aws-cdk:bootstrap-role': 'lookup' } }
    }]
  }),
```

It is also worth noting, however, that this is advised against in the [Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps). Here's an excerpt, but I suggest you check out the whole thing:

> AWS CDK includes a mechanism called context providers to record a
> snapshot of non-deterministic values, allowing future synthesis
> operations produce exactly the same template. The only changes in the
> new template are the changes you made in your code. When you use a
> construct's .fromLookup() method, the result of the call is cached in
> cdk.context.json, which you should commit to version control along
> with the rest of your code to ensure future executions of your CDK app
> use the same value.

What this means in practice is that you should run `cdk synth` once locally, which will perform all the necessary lookups and store the results in `cdk.context.json`. You should then commit that, and your pipeline will use these cached values instead of doing the lookup every time.

As a result, your synth step also won't need to assume the lookup role.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't commit `cdk.context.json` file. After pushing it to the repository, the problem get solved.